# Listing numbers that are not already in a list

Tags: algorithm

How could you design an efficient algorithm that uses the least amount of memory space and outputs, in ascending order, the list of integers in the range 0..255 that are not in a randomly generated list of 100 integers?

The naive approach would be to compare each number from 0 to 255 against the list of 100 integers. This would not be very efficient.

What would be the most efficient approach to solve this?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @PM77-1 That's 32 bytes. Still good enough in my opinion.

Comment: @NicoSchertler - you're right.

Comment: @NicoSchertler it might have been good enough if he would have showed even an bad algorithm he came up with so far I guess. If he doesn't do so he night have a viable question for another stack site I guess but not exactly stack overflow. His question also lacks an exact definition how an 'efficient algorithm' is defined ... so basically its opinion based and thus too broad it seems.

Comment: Sort the list in place then iterate from start to finish, the numbers in between the values are your missing numbers.

Comment: Your first paragraph asks how to do it in "the least amount of memory space." Then you provide an answer and say that it wouldn't be very efficient, and ask how to do it efficiently. Which do you want? Speed or size? There's usually a tradeoff. And does "least amount of memory space" include code bytes, or just data storage space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is:
1) Sort the random list of 100 integers. Split the list so that all elements should be in range (0,255)

2) Iterate through the whole random list, choose the value which is between each random list member:

My sample code in python is:

```
import random
random_list=[]
for x in range(100):
    random_list.append(random.randint(1,255))
random_list.sort()

output_list = []
for insert_number in range(0,random_list[0]):
    output_list.append(insert_number)
for i in range(len(random_list)-1):
    for insert_number in range(random_list[i]+1,random_list[i+1]):
        output_list.append(insert_number)
for insert_number in range(random_list[-1]+1,255):
    output_list.append(insert_number)
print(output_list)
```

Time complexity should be O(n^2) with n is length of the random list, which is 100.